# Will converting from disk to digital keep my saved files?

Tags: ps4

I've been playing Witcher 3 with the disk version, but want to get the digital version of the game.

Will my saves transfer over after making the switch, or perhaps I will need to do something special in order to have my saves transfer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this post [Buying Digital Copies of Games to Replace Discs](http://www.eurogamer.net/forum/thread/289207) , you should be safe as long as you purchase the game within the same region.

The game installation and saves are stored separately. As long as you do not delete your saves, you will be able to pick them up on the digital version.

Comment: That makes sense. I've uninstalled a game before, and the saves were still on the system. So, looks like it should pick up the saves with the same game regardless of how it was installed. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Version makes a differance, too. Its worth noting that diff games also work differently. While they all should work, I can think of atleast one instance that would make diablo a special case

Comment: How would the disk diablo versus digital diablo make a difference as the entire save of your characters are on blizzards server?

Comment: Can it work the other way around? I want to buy shinobi striker as a disk since it’s cheaper after my free trial ended will my data from the free trial be transferred to the disk?