# Do disc saves on PS4 work with digital games?

Tags: ps4, uncharted-4

I got Uncharted 4 early and managed to get up to Chapter 10. I also had a digital version of the game preordered which just unlocked at midnight and I'm having some trouble getting the digital version of my game to recognise my existing save.

When I boot the game up it only gives me the option of "New game" and not "Continue", like it does when I put the disc in.

Do disc saves work with digital games? Both the games are PAL versions. I really hope I haven't lost my progress.

I've uploaded some images of the storage on my console.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2O98N.jpg

The disc version and digital version seem to have different data stored separately. Is there a way to fix this?

If I delete the saved game data from the digital game, when I go to boot the digital game up, it just creates a new game save and doesn't try to load my existing physical save.

Comment: the digital game seems to be of an updated version (1.02) unlike the disc version which is 1.00, it's possible that the versions have incompatible save files, are you able to update the disc version to 1.02? if you can, save your game again with this version and it might just fix the issue

Comment: Not putting this as an answer, only because it was on PS3, not PS4: I once rented Thief for PS3 and made a decent amount of progress in it. Several months later, I bought the digital version from the PS store (and I had not deleted the save files), but could not access my disc-based save files.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to access the saves as long as it is the same region.  You will need to delete the game first and then re-download the digital copy.

Sources:
https://www.reddit.com/r/PS4/comments/3sn0vu/disc_and_digital_copies_game_saves_still_work/
[Will converting from disk to digital keep my saved files?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/239166/will-converting-from-disk-to-digital-keep-my-saved-files)

Comment: **Same region** is the key word here.